Необычное употребление прямой речи
Возник вопрос по поводу оформления необычной конструкции. Не разбираюсь в таких тонкостях, нашла единственное, что вроде как подходит под данную ситуацию: §153. Если я правильно поняла, то в данном случае прямая речь должна быть с маленькой буквы, но интуитивно мне это не нравится, я пишу так:

Под Надин возглас «Давайте хорошо проведём время!» компания отправилась в лес.

Видела ещё вариант ( §136 ). В этом случае предложение вообще будет выглядеть так:

Под Надин возглас: «Давайте хорошо проведём время!» — компания отправилась в лес.

Помогите разобраться, как тут всё-таки поступить.

• § 153 (выделение кавычками необычно употребляемых слов) для этого предложения никак не подходит. Здесь слова в кавычках являются прямой речью.
• Под Надин возглас «Давайте хорошо проведём время!» компания отправилась в лес.
Всё правильно. Тут "работает" §136, пункт "г" (ПАС под ред. Лопатина):

если прямая речь непосредственно включается в авторское предложение в качестве его члена, то она заключается в кавычки, знаки же препинания ставятся по условиям авторского предложения: Сказав Гричмару фразу «Легкой жизни не бывает, есть лишь легкая смерть», Крымов поймал на себе беспокойный, предупреждающий взгляд Стишова (Бонд.).

Пример:
Под возглас «Куда? Вот бедовая девчонка!» я соскочила с коляски на ходу, саквояж больно стукнул по ноге... (Е. Боброва).
• Под Надин возглас: «Давайте хорошо проведём время!» — компания отправилась в лес.
Такой вариант пунктуации тоже верен.

Если прямая речь оказывается внутри слов автора , то она заключается в кавычки, а перед ней ставится двоеточие; прямая речь начинается с прописной буквы. После прямой речи знаки препинания расставляются следующим образом:
<...>
в) тире ставится, если прямая речь заканчивается многоточием, вопросительным или восклицательным знаком: ... Петр Михайлыч хотел сказать: «Не впутывайся ты, пожалуйста, не в свои дела!» — но промолчал (Ч.)...

Примеры:
Под возгласы слева: «Правильно, верно!» — я сказал, что в государстве нужна какая-то голова, осмысливающая весь большой процесс народной жизни во время войны... (В. Шульгин);
Люди ликовали, все желали щедрого орошения под возглас: «Христос воскресе!» — и поворачивали улыбающиеся лица на взмахи руки с кропилом (сборник).
